# Is it possible to externalize and/or reuse tikz pictures when used as backgrounds for the page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, tikz-external

My experiments with externalisation have run into trouble. One issue is that it seems that I cannot externalise a `tikz` picture used as a page background:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,positioning}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw [blue] (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This fails, I think, because the position is not correct until the second run but with externalisation, `tikz` never recompiles the code and so the faulty positioning never gets corrected.

I know there are ways of working around this by compiling the picture independently and then setting it as background wallpaper, for example. What I would like to know is if it is possible to do this using externalisation so that I don't have to think about separate files. (This project already includes many files and it is already hard to keep track of them.)

Alternatively, is it possible to *reuse* a `tikz` picture *within* a single compilation run? I notice that if I `\input` a `tikz` picture multiple times, it seems to get compiled multiple times. If there were a way of avoiding that, it would definitely help even though it would only work for a certain proportion of the pictures I'm using.

Comment: If you box the `tikzpicture` I'd expect you could reuse it several times without multiple compilations.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks but I'm not sure how to do that. If I put the entire thing in a box then it doesn't get positioned correctly either. (At least, I assume that's the problem. It doesn't show up at all, at least.) I think I'm not understanding the suggestion.

Comment: I've never worked with externalization so perhaps my idea doesn't work (it was just a guessing). I'll delete these comments shortly.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Oh, I took the externalisation out to test. I just tried putting the picture in a savebox in the preamble and then doing `\usebox` in the document. But that was probably naïve. I'm only using externalisation because the stupid document is taking so long to compile. But I'm using fancy headings etc. which use (very simple) `tikz` code. Some of them just use the same code so if I could just repeat it, that would help a bit even without externalisation.

Comment: I see. When I suggested the box I was thinking in using some package such as `background`, but perhaps this is now what you are after.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The trouble is that the background is defined using `current page` nodes and the positioning doesn't seem to come out correctly in that case. On the other hand, I'm ashamed to admit that I've never actually managed to use your package successfully although I have tried. I always end up using `wallpaper` instead but I can't do that here, I don't think, without just compiling the images as entirely separate files.

Comment: Oh, it's a shame you haven't been able to use my package. Perhaps some day we could discuss the problems that you have experienced with the package?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sure. I'm sure it is me. Nobody else seems to have trouble ;).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14548/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-cfr)

Comment: Ah, then when you want you can e-mail me. Can you see the chat room messages so I can leave my e-mail address there for a few seconds while you see it?

Comment: My e-mail is there. Let me know when you see it so I can delete it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Got it. I cannot now remember what I had trouble with so I will probably wait and try to find an occasion to use the package so that I can hopefully figure out what the issue is. (Or maybe I will find I can now understand how to use it...) Thanks.

Comment: OK. I think we can delete all these messages to tidy up a bit?

Comment: @cfr Dealing with exactly the same problem right now. Did you find a way which allows externalization?

Comment: @hbaderts Not really. I use a mixture of the answer I got here (where that's an option) and a system of turning externalisation on selectively only for those pictures where it works. So some pictures are externalised and some not. It does significantly reduce compilation time, but it is not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that works without externalization.  The trick is to set the box after `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox\mytikzpic
\AddEverypageHook{\usebox{\mytikzpic}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,positioning}
%\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\savebox\mytikzpic{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw [blue] (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\lipsum[1-13]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely helpful since I'm assuming the contents will be typeset only once. As given, your code didn't initially look very promising since `everypage` does not suggest it might contain solutions for only some pages. But it turns out it offers `\AddThispageHook` and it further turns out this in compatible with `standalone`, `tikz`'s `remember picture, overlay` and `current page`. I'd still prefer a way of using externalisation because this method won't work with stuff where I pass keys to the `tikz` code but this nonetheless saves one picture being typeset 10+ times!

Comment: @cfr Indeed, I should have mentioned `\AddThispageHook` as one of its options.  And I agree that, unless I'm sorely mistaken, the placing of the item in a box means that it will be typeset but once.  Obviously, a solution involving externalization would be ideal, but at least you now have a fallback.

Comment: Yes, thanks again. I've upvoted but not marked this solved yet just because it would be ideal to find a solution which allowed externalisation. (I can't use this fallback with my repeated `\maketitle` commands because I'm passing values as keys i.e. it is not precisely the same image each time even though the `\input` `tikzpicture` is the same.) But this works nicely for the case where I'm using identical stuff repeatedly and putting the different stuff over the top only in the main document - thanks again.

Comment: @cfr I'm not a `tikz` user, so I'm not exactly sure the way keys work their way into an image, otherwise I could give it more thought.